Chart Formatting in Excel Scripts
im relativley new to Excel Scripts and i need your help.
I have build an Excel Script which i want to add to my power automate flow, to generate graphs automatically with a predefined template.
In general i want to add vertical gridlines to the graph so that it becomes easier for the reader to look at the data. On the right side i haven't figured out how to set the x-Axis with the labels to the bottom of the graph, now it does not look uniform with regards to the left graph.
any help is appreciated :)
// Formating Graph1
//-----------------------------------------------
AAchart.getTitle().setVisible(false);
AAchart.getLegend().setVisible(false);


AAseriesC.getFormat().getLine().setColor("#00B050");
AAseriesG.getFormat().getLine().setColor("#FF0000");
AAseriesH.getFormat().getLine().setColor("#00B050"); //green

let AALineFormatC = AAseriesC.getFormat().getLine();
AALineFormatC.setWeight(2);
let AALineFormatG = AAseriesG.getFormat().getLine();
AALineFormatG.setWeight(2);
let AALineFormatH = AAseriesH.getFormat().getLine();
AALineFormatH.setWeight(2);

AAseriesC.setMarkerStyle(ExcelScript.ChartMarkerStyle.none);
AAseriesG.setMarkerStyle(ExcelScript.ChartMarkerStyle.none);
AAseriesH.setMarkerStyle(ExcelScript.ChartMarkerStyle.none);

let AAseriesAB = AAchart.getSeries()[0];
AAseriesAB.setMarkerStyle(ExcelScript.ChartMarkerStyle.circle);
AAseriesAB.setMarkerBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
AAseriesAB.setMarkerSize(6);




So why not build a template with the charts formatted etc ready to go then just dump the fresh data in and then save as Newfile? That was the route we used for over 100,000 files...

@SolarMike thank you for your response. I already build a template the way i want my data to be presented. But I'm not sure how to access this template in the excel script itsself. In my script i generate a graph like this: let chart = Sheet.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.line,rangeAB); I used the standard Chart Type line but is it possible to input my template here ?

Please edit your question instead of adding information in comments.

How do I ask a good question?
Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Relocate Axis-X location to bottom of the chart.
Microsoft documentation:

ExcelScript.ChartAxis interface setPosition(position)


ExcelScript.ChartAxis interface getMinimum()

function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let sht = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    let cht = sht.getCharts()[0];
    let axisX = cht.getAxes().getValueAxis();
    // axisX.setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartAxisPosition.automatic);
    axisX.setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartAxisPosition.custom) ;
    axisX.setPositionAt(axisX.getMinimum());
}



taller thank you so much, this works perfectly :)
